# MPNS Windows Phone configuration

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mpns, windows-dev-center

I'm developing notification on Windows Phone using IBM MobileFirst + Cordova. I have a developer account on Microsoft Dev Center and I viewed probably all tutorials from Microsoft site and I'm confused. What steps I need to do right now to configure my app or DevCenter or WebService to start sending/answering notifications (I want to use MPNS)?

I set up a application-descriptor.xml ( added  ) and "open channel" and I have a URI, but what steps I need to take to answer notifications from webservices?

Comment: which version of MFP you are using ?

Comment: @VittalPai [based on this article](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/#setupWP8)

Comment: For MPNS ( un-authenticated) you do not need to add anything but the <pushSender /> tag. This should get you MPNS. Can you try this out? To see if notifications are working

Comment: Could you tell me, is there any difference between un-authenticated/authenticated, it is only a limited amount of massages or maybe something else?

Comment: Regarding unauthenticated and Authenticated Mode, you can refer to [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221549.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I hope that is only difference between this two and Microsoft didn't hide something, thanks :)